# Python script processes and generates a result in html format. I want it post on web using WSGI

Tags: python-3.x, web-applications, python-requests, mod-wsgi

how do I call from myapp.wsgi my existing testreport.py .
testreport.py processes DB fetches a result in HTML format .

**myapp.wsgi**

**testreport.py **

```
def getFormattedMailBody(data,color,frm,to):
    htable ="""<html>
        <b>Bp Report for %s to %s.</b> <br />
    <br /><table style=\"border: 3px solid olive;\" border=1>
    <tr style=\"background-color:%s; color:white;\">
        <td><b>S. No.</b></td><td><b> Business </b></td><td><b> DB Name / Tags </b></td><td><b> AWS ID </b></td><td><b> AWS DB InstanceIP </b></td><td><b> Backup / AMI ID </b></td><td><b> Start Date & Time
        </b></td><td><b> End Date & Time </b></td><td><b>Tentative Time Taken to backup AMI</b></td><td><b> Backup Copies </b></td><td><b>Group Name</b></td><td><b>Owner</b></td><td><b>Mailing List</b></td><td><b>Tagname</b></td></tr>"""%(frm,to,color)

    #htable=u'<table border="1" bordercolor=000000 cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" style="table-layout:fixed;vertical-align:bottom;font-size:13px;font-family:verdana,sans,sans-serif;border-collapse:collapse;border:1px solid rgb(130,130,130)" >'
#    data[0] = ['<b>' + datetime.datetime.strptime(i, '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S') + u'</b>' for i in data[0]] 
    n=1
    for row in data:
            newrow = '<tr style=\"color:%s;\"><td>%s </td>'%(color,n)
        newrow = newrow + ''.join([u'<td align="right" style="padding:1px 4px">' + unicode(x) + u'</td>' for x in row])
        newrow += '</tr>'
        htable+= newrow
        n+=1
    htable += '</table></html>'
    return htable
```

```
def send_mail(grpname,rows,receiver):
        datefrom=dt.date.today()-dt.timedelta(days=2)
        dateto=dt.date.today()-dt.timedelta(days=1)
        html=getFormattedMailBody(rows,Color("green"), datefrom, dateto)
        print(html)

def query_mysql(procedurename):
        try:
                conn = mysql.connector.connect( host=hostname, port=port, database=database, user=username, password=password)
                cur = conn.cursor()
                cur.callproc(procedurename)
                cur.stored_results()
                for result in cur.stored_results():
                        global results1
                        results1 = result.fetchall()
                header1 = [i[0] for i in result.description]
                rows1 = [list(i) for i in results1]
                cur.close()
                conn.close()
                return rows1

        except Error as e:
                print(e)

def sort_on_groups(rows):

        groups=[]
        for row in rows:
                if row[9] not in groups:
                        groups.append(row[9])

        mail='i@.com'
        send_mail('In',rows,mail)

a=query_mysql('reportdata')

html=sort_on_groups(a)
```

This code shows how testreport in fetching record from db and then processing it changing uin html

Comment: Import whatever function/variable/class you need from _testreport.py_ and call that function inside your other python script. It's not clear from the code you're showing where you've tried to use _testreport.py_ and what the exact problem is.

Comment: Using above when I open the url I get on Web Page : Welcome to mod_wsgi Test Page.What I want is to use the output of my testreport.py on Web Page .

Comment: In testreport.py >> access mysql fetch table , then create html trying to send this on web

Comment: your post is tagged with "django" so I suppose you're using django but it doesn't look like you're using django at all, are you? Anyway, you have a function returning HTML, so you can just write a django view that calls that function and returns that HTML in an `HttpResponse`.

Comment: If you're not using Django but just want your wsgi script to return the html, then just replace the part from the default wsgi.py (which you removed from your question) that creates the html with the call to you function.

Comment: I am not using Django and I want my script to return html . But for instance if I do the below :   def prin():
        h='<html> <body>Hello World</body></html>'
        return h

#html=prin()
def application(environ,start_response):
    status = '200 OK'
    response_body = html
    response_headers = [
        ('Content-Type', 'text/html'),
        ('Content-Length', str(len(response_body)))
    ]
    start_response(status,response_headers)
    return [response_body]

Comment: But , if I call my function from within def application(environment,start_response): I get no output

Comment: Show us the code that you’re using in your question not in your comment. Also just show the minimum code needed to reproduce your issue so probably the code from your comment is sufficient. But it’s not readable as comment.